# Shortcut to merge changeset in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

Is the only way to merge an individual changeset in Visual Studio to open the Source Control Explorer, right-click on the node to merge, and select your specific changeset? A lot of times when I check in a changeset I have to merge it right away into another branch. It would be awesome if there was a simple way to do that right after I check it in without having to open the Source Control Explorer. I'm using VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this in my extension.
After CheckIn, I open a small form to choose target destination.

Then, I call tf.exe to do merge. Like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = GetTFExeFileName();
pInfo.Arguments = string.Format("merge /recursive /lock:none /version:c{0}~c{0} \"{1}\" \"{2}\"",
    changesetId, sourceLocalPath, targetLocalPath);
Process.Start(pInfo);
```

To open my form after checkIn, I do:

```
VersionControlServer vcServer = GetVersionControlServer();
vcServer.CommitCheckin += YourMethod;
```

Please, let me know if the above code helps.

Thanks. Regards, Wilsade